# Batch programming: finding a given string in another program's - maybe delayed - output

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to **start the Apache service** on my Windows 7 **with the help of a batch program**. That's a really simple task, all I have to do is type this:

```
net start Apache2.2
```

then press Enter; **BUT I must have admin rights** to do so, otherwise I get some error messages like this:

```
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

**It's OK, but I would like to check the output of the "net start XY" command, and in case the output (or the response) contains the mentioned "Access is denied" string, then I would like to do some other things in another part of the batch program (output some custom error messages and stuff).**
I tried to check the output with [FIND](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/find.php) command like this (**IT DOESN'T WORK THE WAY IT SHOULD**):

```
@echo off
set search_string=Access is denied
echo We are looking for this string: "%search_string%"
rem set errorlevel =
net start Apache2.2 | find /i "%search_string%" > nul
echo The errorlevel number is: "%ERRORLEVEL%"
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto gotcha
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 goto not_found
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 goto para

:gotcha
echo OK, found it
echo So maybe you don't have the rights to do so...
goto end

:not_found
echo String not found...
echo So this would mean there are no problems related to admin-rights... but YES, there are... :-S
goto end

:para
echo Something's not OK...
goto end

:end
echo -- END --
pause
```

Starting this batch program without admin rights, it outputs the mentioned "Access is denied", so it should jump to "gotcha" label. Unfortunately it doesn't work fine, it jumps to "not_found", which means it didn't find the given string ("Access is denied").

Maybe the problem is that

```
net send XY
```

command sends the "Access is denied" output a little bit delayed, just after checking for admin rights, and find doesn't take care about it anymore. But it's just guessing, I don't know the real explanation of the problem.

BUT the code above DOES work when I create another little batch program which just simply echoes the lines above with the "Access is denied" string. So the other little batch program, which shows that 'find' command can work the way it's written like above, looks like this:

```
@echo off
echo.
echo System error 5 has occurred.
echo.
echo Access is denied. blabla
echo.
```

I saved this file with the name "write_accessdenied_stuff.bat".

After that, I tried the code above, but instead of the "net send XY...." row I wrote this one:

```
write_accessdenied_stuff.bat | find /i "%search_string%" > nul
```

so the beginning of the code is changed like this, and **IT WORKS**:

```
@echo off
set search_string=Access is denied
echo We are looking for this string: "%search_string%"
write_accessdenied_stuff.bat | find /i "%search_string%" > nul
..........
..........
```

With this one, the find command sets the errorlevel to 0, which means it has found the string given, so the execution of the program jumps to "gotcha" label.

**So how can I find the little bit delayed "Access is denied" output of the "net start XY" command?**

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: The error could be coming out on stderr so you should try redirecting that, too.  I don't have a windows computer handy so I'll just leave this as a comment. Here's an answer that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918619/redirect-batch-stderr-to-file

Comment: Thank you very much, indiv, that was correct! :) I voted up your comment too! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
net start Apache2.2 2>&1 | find /i "%search_string%" > nul
```

in order to tie STDERR to the standard output.

Comment: Wow, that's perfect, Benoit!! Aaaahh, why didn't I think of it... :P Now it works like a charm, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry to ask again, but I have just one more question: what if I would like to search for more possible response strings, like an if-else statement? E.g. I would like to find "Access is denied" string first, and if it's not found, after that, I would look for "The requested service has already been started." string, without any filewriting. So for example in the first case I would set the errorlevel to for example "98", in the other case "99" or something like that. I hope I could explain my problem clearly... :P Could you help in that too? Thanks!

Comment: this is a new question - log it in as one.